# AngularJS: Load dialog for ng-repeat with large number of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to come up with a way to display a load dialog while the items in ng-repeat are being rendered. The use case is as follows:
User clicks a toggle switch to display a list of items
A directive is shown that contains an ng-repeat of items
The list of items show up almost instantly on a PC. But on a mobile device it takes a few seconds for the list to show up. This can cause the user to tap the toggle switch multiple times resulting in the list being hidden and shown.

Here's my HTML mark-up:

```
<div jqm-theme="b">
    <div style=""  jqm-theme="a" jqm-textinput ng-model="projectFilter"
         placeholder="Filter Project Areas...">
    </div>

    <div style="height:12px;"></div>

    <ul jqm-listview style="padding-top: 12px;">

        <project-display title="My Project Areas" filter="projectFilter" projects="myProjects"
                         select-project="selectProject" show="true">
        </project-display>

        <li jqm-li-entry jqm-theme="b" class="ui-icon-alt">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a class="projTitle">Toggle All Projects</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right;">
                    <div jqm-flip mini="true" jqm-theme="d" ng-model="allSwitch.value"                         
                         on-label="On" on-value="1" off-label="Off" off-value="0"                                     
                         default-value="0" ng-click="toggleAllProj()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <project-display title="All Project Areas" filter="projectFilter" projects="projects"
                         select-project="selectProject" show="allSwitch.value">
        </project-display>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Here's the directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('projectDisplay', ['$location', function($location) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        title: '@',
        filter: '=',
        projects: '=',
        selectProject: '=',
        show: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template/directives/project-display.html'
};
}]);
```

Here's the directive's template:

```
<div ng-show="show">
  <span style="margin-left:13px" jqm-li-divider>{{title}} ({{projects.length}})</span>
  <ul jqm-listview style="padding-top: 12px;">
    <li jqm-li-link jqm-theme="a" style="margin-left:13px" class="ui-icon-alt" ng-click="selectProject(project)"
    ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: filter">
    <a>{{project.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using Angular JQM's $loadDialog which can be shown and hidden by explicitly calling the separate methods or it can also display until a promise is resolved.

Is there a way to monitor when all items within an ng-repeat have been rendered? I appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Check this article http://blog.stackfull.com/2013/02/angularjs-virtual-scrolling-part-1/ ( and part 2 ) it is not exactly what you are asking, but it could solve your issue.

Comment: Interesting article. I appreciate the post. However, I would not be able to implement this because the user needs to be able to filter by all objects in the list, not just those currently visible.

Comment: for directives bound directly to repeated elements, `ng-repeat` sets `scope.$last=true` for last item. Might use that to hide loader and could do filtering using a function in controller instead of using markup filter, which would allow setting a loader variable/event whenever projects digest kicks in

Comment: @sh3nan1gans it doesnot contradict with what article says. question is to just generate DOM only for fraction of records on the screen.